# Mysql - get last post from category

Tags: php, mysql

I have this structure (tables) of forum

[image: tables]

I want to select last post (row from forum_post table) from category.

SQL so far:

```
SELECT * FROM table_post 
WHERE topic_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_topic WHERE category_id = {$id})       
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Question: How to modify this select to achieve my goal?

Comment: ... And the question is? Why not add that bit

Comment: *"I want to select last post (row from forum_post table) from category."* It's maybe not a question, but I don't think it's really hard to guess what is the question..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard - But follows is a query that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that "last" means the biggest id, I would suggest `order by` and `limit`:

```
select fp.*
from forum_post fp join
     forum_topic ft
     on fp.topic_id = ft.id
where ft.category_id = $id
order by fp.id desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: "last" indeed means MAX(id)